# Deploy multiple databases with SSDT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

We have an existing system with multiple databases on one SQL Server instance, and we want to deploy database changes using SQL Server Data Tools. Thus I've created a solution with one database project per database.

When I run a build, it creates a `.dacpac` file for each project. Ideally we want to bundle the deployment of database changes, such that all databases are deployed in one shot. I've seen that database projects can reference other projects and suppose that you can use this mechanism for bundling as well - but I am reluctant to add references just for the sake of deployment.

What is the recommended way to deploy multiple databases in one package?

Comment: You can check [this blog post](https://www.sqlshack.com/deployment-several-databases-using-sql-server-data-tools-team-foundation-server/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this. By default, each database gets its own dacpac. You can set up a script that can build/publish all databases in one shot, but it will do them one at a time.  I created a basic batch file some time ago that would build all of the dacpacs and publish each of them in order.

Comment: Okay, it is clear to me that you can do that kind of script. I am mostly interested in a kind of transactional behavior - if (say) the deployment of the third database fails, I would ideally like to roll back the rollout of the previous databases. I suppose one can work around this with database backups, though.

Comment: That gets really tricky with anything that's not purely code because the DB has a state. If you've done any sort of data migration, you have to account for that properly.  You could potentially keep a stash of versioned dacpacs and revert using those, but your better bet is to have a test system set up somewhere to verify that everything will go smoothly if you need everything to roll at the same time. Do you normally have issues w/ the SSDT upgrades failing?

Comment: We have a time window during deployment where none of the databases is in use, so a rollback in case one or more failing dacpacs seems feasible. We have barely started using SSDT. Hitherto we had used batches of SQL scripts, with a poor feedback/escalation mechanism when something went wrong.

Comment: I'd probably recommend looking at PS to do the deploys. There are a couple of projects already in the works so you don't need to re-invent the wheel. However, rollbacks are going to be tricky w/ SSDT if you do anything beyond schema changes. Data movement will still need special handling outside of SSDT to put things back.  The schema changes would be relatively easy if you store your dacpacs somewhere so you can revert.

Answer (score 0):

Surprising there isn’t a solid answer to this. I know red gate has sql automate tool, but your company will have to pay for it. Interested if you got a solid answer

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33332232)